# Gmail app vs. browser, in terms of data consumption

Tags: gmail, data-monitoring

Does the Gmail app use more data than just using a web browser to check my emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app definitely uses less data than a browser, because it only loads the email's contents, while the website loads a lot of stuff along with it.

The app needs to download just the gmail content and some information about it ( sender, cc etc. ).

If you're worried about data limits, then go for the app. It's both faster and uses less data.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume less, as all formatting is built into the app, while using the web browser you would need to download the 'whole' page including Gmails UI etc

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know the data consumption of Gmail App will be less than that of browser. Because all the styling info are built into the app itself, it only need to get the raw text data, which may be in the form of ***JSON or XML***. But in case of browser it has to download styling info such as ***CSS*** and client side scripts such as ***Javascript*** along with email content.